# Pull data from second HTML table using DOM, ignore first table

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have the below PHP script which is run via a command prompt and it works fine if there is only one table on a page but if I have two tables on a page it will just try and pull the first one out, is there a way I can say in certain instances to ignore the first table and process the second table only?

I have no control of the HTML so can't target the table by using an ID.

**HTML**

```
<html>
</head>
...
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Problem Table</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Annoying table in the way!</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <hr/>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Asset</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>34234234</td>
            <td>Website3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>34234234</td>
            <td>Website4</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

**PHP**

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$html = $dom->loadHTMLFile($url);

$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;

$tables = $dom->getElementsByTagName('table');
$rows = $tables->item(0)->getElementsByTagName('tr');
$cols = $rows->item(0)->getElementsByTagName('th');
$row_headers = null;

foreach($cols AS $node) {
    $row_headers[] = $node->nodeValue;
}

$table = array();
$rows = $tables->item(0)->getElementsByTagName('tr');
foreach($rows AS $row) {
    $cols = $row->getElementsByTagName('td');
    $row = array();
    $i = 0;
    foreach($cols AS $node) {
        if ($row_headers != null) {
            $row[$row_headers[$i]] = $node->nodeValue;
        }
        $i++;
    }
    if (!empty($row)) {
        $table[] = $row;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use ```getElementById```? Then you just have to modify ```<table``` to ```<table id="something">```.

If you try to be smarter while always selecting all table elements, eventually you will run into problems. There can be an arbitrary number of tables before, so even if you select the second table when there is more than one, you can still be picking an unwanted table.

Comment: @GCC404, I don't have control of the HTML which stops me from going down this route.

Comment: Why don't you use jQuery and an id? Be as simple as `$("table#table-ID").html("Your html");`

Comment: @SamSwift, it's being run via a commad prompt so jquery can't be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with @GCC404 that you should target your elements better using an ID or class as this could easily lead to mistakes.

However, if you specifically want to target the last table, you just need to replace the `0` with the number of items found minus 1:

```
$rows = $tables->item( $tables->length - 1 )->getElementsByTagName('tr');
// etc.
```

Comment: I don't have control of the HTML so I can't target it by an ID.

Comment: @llanato In that case you could try this, targetting the last table on the page as described in my answer.

Answer (score -1):

When using `getElementsByTagName()`, you can specify an index with [DOMNodelist::item](http://php.net/manual/en/domnodelist.item.php).

This should probably only be used when you have no control over the source HTML or you are sure there will always be two tables, but I'd recommend just setting an id/class for each table if you are in control of the HTML.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$html = $dom->loadHTMLFile($url);

$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;

$tables = $dom->getElementsByTagName('table');
$rows = $tables->item(1)->getElementsByTagName('tr');
$cols = $rows->item(1)->getElementsByTagName('th');
$row_headers = null;

foreach($cols AS $node) {
    $row_headers[] = $node->nodeValue;
}

$table = array();
$rows = $tables->item(1)->getElementsByTagName('tr');
foreach($rows AS $row) {
    $cols = $row->getElementsByTagName('td');
    $row = array();
    $i = 0;
    foreach($cols AS $node) {
        if ($row_headers != null) {
            $row[$row_headers[$i]] = $node->nodeValue;
        }
        $i++;
    }
    if (!empty($row)) {
        $table[] = $row;
    }
}
```